# in javascript dom, escaping characters in querySelector()

Tags: javascript, dom, escaping

I discovered that *almost all* non-alphanumeric characters must be quoted in `querySelector()` and `querySelectorAll()`.  From my testing:

```
for( var i=32; i<127; i++ ) { 
   var ch = String.fromCharCode(i);
   try{ document.querySelector("[a"+ch+"b]") }
   catch(e) { console.log( i + ' = ' + ch ); }
};
```

Only "-" and "_" did *not* need to be escaped.  This requires a specialized `replace` type function for arguments to `querySelector` to make sure they are filtered correctly.  Other functions (eg, `setAttribute`, `getAttribute`) do not need escaping.

I am unable to find documentation to verify testing. For example, what about Unicode characters in an attribute name?

Comment: The selector grammar is in section 10.2 of this document: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/.

Comment: good catch.  goes down to `ident ::= [-]?{nmstart}{nmchar}*` - very clean.  interestingly non-ascii, escaped and Unicode are pretty much synonymous.  reckon the God of DOM likes for me to write replace functions.

Answer (score 1):

The [selector grammar](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#lex) is as follows:

```
ident     [-]?{nmstart}{nmchar}*
name      {nmchar}+
nmstart   [_a-z]|{nonascii}|{escape}
nonascii  [^\0-\177]
unicode   \\[0-9a-f]{1,6}(\r\n|[ \n\r\t\f])?
escape    {unicode}|\\[^\n\r\f0-9a-f]
nmchar    [_a-z0-9-]|{nonascii}|{escape}
num       [0-9]+|[0-9]*\.[0-9]+
string    {string1}|{string2}
string1   \"([^\n\r\f\\"]|\\{nl}|{nonascii}|{escape})*\"
string2   \'([^\n\r\f\\']|\\{nl}|{nonascii}|{escape})*\'
invalid   {invalid1}|{invalid2}
invalid1  \"([^\n\r\f\\"]|\\{nl}|{nonascii}|{escape})*
invalid2  \'([^\n\r\f\\']|\\{nl}|{nonascii}|{escape})*
nl        \n|\r\n|\r|\f
w         [ \t\r\n\f]*

D         d|\\0{0,4}(44|64)(\r\n|[ \t\r\n\f])?
E         e|\\0{0,4}(45|65)(\r\n|[ \t\r\n\f])?
N         n|\\0{0,4}(4e|6e)(\r\n|[ \t\r\n\f])?|\\n
O         o|\\0{0,4}(4f|6f)(\r\n|[ \t\r\n\f])?|\\o
T         t|\\0{0,4}(54|74)(\r\n|[ \t\r\n\f])?|\\t
V         v|\\0{0,4}(58|78)(\r\n|[ \t\r\n\f])?|\\v
```